# While Committing Changes, I constantly see and commit different redundant files. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: git, visual-studio, asp.net-core, github, commit

[image]

As I can see in the screenshot, although I only made changes to the CustomExtension.cs file, +99 Changes has occurred and this is a problem for me. Is there a way I can fix it? I do it in Visual Studio.

Comment: You should not track the files produced by building the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need specify a `.gitignore` file. This is intended to filter files that should not be tracked and stored in a repository - for example build results (`dll`), visual studio specific files (`.suo`) etc. That's a common practice in programming.

When you create a new project in GitHub you may want to select from default list (see screenshot) [image]

Here are [details](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) of `.gitignore` file format.

Comment: Additionally, you can create your own `.gitignore` file in the local repository, just like you would any other text file. Here is a sample for VS: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: Although I have added the .gitignore file to my project, the changes continue to appear. Will it improve after this commit or is it better to open a different project and continue from there? I still see changes as a result of 'git status'.

Comment: If you'd already committed undesired files then you will need to explicitly remove all of them and commit the change @MehmetSerkanEkinci